# ASP.Net odd behavior with fileupload control

Tags: asp.net, excel, file-upload

I am trying to read an excel file from a client's PC. I am using an ASP fileupload control. When I am trying to read the file, its trying to open the file selected in the wrong folder. The file is located on the D: drive and it is trying to open it in the C: drive.

The following is what I am passing into a function:

```
    fpc.AddSpecs(ref model, this.fuSpecs.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
```

The following is the connection string in the function:

```
        switch ( postedfile.Substring(postedfile.LastIndexOf('.') + 1) )
        {
            case "xls":
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + postedfile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
                break;
            case "xlsx":
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + postedfile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2";
                break;
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you consider checking the value of the postedFile variable ..

Comment: yes and the value is just the filename. there is not path

Comment: why the client path is relevant? you have the file name and content - save it wherever you want in your server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Save the file on your server:

```
string uploadedFilePath = "URL" + System.IO.Path.GetFilename(fileUpload1.FileName));
fileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadedFilePath);
```

2- Assign the value of your `connString` variable:

```
switch ( postedfile.Substring(postedfile.LastIndexOf('.') + 1) )        
{            
    case "xls":                
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + uploadedFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";                
        break;            
    case "xlsx":                
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + uploadedFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2";                
        break;        
}
```

---

Check to the following link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/20/fileupload-control-doesn-t-give-full-path-help.aspx